Pairing a google speaker to a pi4b with digiamp hat
I have a Pi4b setup with a digiamp audio hat installed with raspbian.
I'd like to stream from a google hub to it which I believe supports bluetooth 5.
I also have a megaboom bluetooth speaker.
The hub can pair to bluetooth speakers and use them as there default speaker.
I can put the megaboom in pairing mode then quickly connect the hub to it without any interaction beyond picking the megaboom from the list then play music.
When I make the pi discoverable, google  sees it, and I can select the pi which then takes ages to pair. I have to actively accept the pairing on pi. Google home does not present any interaction it just seems to expect to pair without any.
The pi says its paired but not connected or trusted. The hub thinks it's paired but won't set it as a default speaker.
There's also an error during pairing in the journal about failing to get io data from the handsfree set.
I'm a techy ex programmer but new to pi.I've been looking at this for a week happily learning but I've just hit a wall now. I've looked through forums many of which seem outdated or contradictory.
When I first got the pi strangely with many many attempts it did pair and play music but after a power outage I can't reconnect, or repair?
I can pair and play music from my phone.
I'm now getting a new card and reinstalling the os and try from scratch.
Any pointers on how to debug what's happening, or direction on what I'm not doing would be hugely welcome!

You might need to change the pairing agent on the RPi so it doesn't prompt during pairing. I only know how to do this from the command line with bluetoothctl then pairable on, discoverable on, agent NoInputNoOutput,  default-agent

You may also need to delete the existing device pairing before trying again

Ditto -- if you are using some GUI widget on the deskop and it doesn't offer this functionality try bluetoothctl, you should be able to use it to pair then set the device as trusted etc.

Thanks for the feedback, I got another p4 for Xmas for other usage, will use this without audio hat and try your suggestion there on a clean install later today, but it sounds like you both think it's the expected user interaction that's the issue, bluetoothctl is fine, once there's a successful pairing that both devices are happy with I should be sorted, thanks again
